# Proving Cardinality of Cosets in Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, cardinals

*****************updated question**************

The question starts off like this:

Let $H$ be a subgroup of a finite group $G$. Prove that $|Ha| = |Hb|$ by
proving that there exists a bijection $f : Ha \rightarrow Hb$. Find this bijection.

I know that I have to show injective and surjective but want to know if anyone thinks this is correct in this fashion

$$Let\ a\in G, \ y, x \in Ha,then \ x=ra, y=sa\ for\ some\ r,s \in H. $$
$$we\ define\ f:Ha \rightarrow Hb\ by \ f(x)=hb$$
$$suppose \ f(x)=f(y)$$
$$rb=sb\ for\ some\ r,s \in H$$
  $$r=s$$
  $$xa^{-1}=ya^{-1}\ (from\ x=ra\ and\ y=sa)$$
$$x=y$$
This shows injective. for the onto part this is really wanted to check
$$let\ x\in Ha, y\in Hb\ and\ a,b \in G\  such\ that$$
$$x=sa,\ y=sb\ for \ some\ s \in H$$
$$then\ f(x)=sb$$
$$=yb^{-1}b\ (from \ y=sb)$$
$$=y$$
Thus, we have shown that $\forall y \in Hb, \exists\ x \in Ha \ such
\ that f(x)=y  $

here we have shown the function is also surjective and hence a bijection exist between $Ha$ and $Hb$ and therefore we know then  $|Ha|=|Hb|$

Comment: What do you know about $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @BillO'Haran  This was all the information given.

Comment: @BillO'Haran I think i have solved it now. I updated the question for you. I think i get what you meant when you said what do we know about a and b. I would imagine you meant for me to see what kind of properties they have in relation to being a member of a coset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the cosets there is $H=H1$. If, for every $a\in G$, you find a bijection $f_a\colon H\to Ha$, then the required bijection $Ha\to Hb$ can be obtained as the composition $f_b\circ f_a^{-1}$.

An obvious candidate for $f_a$ is the map $f_a\colon H\to Ha$, $f_a(h)=ha$; can you prove it's indeed bijective? If so, what's its inverse?

Comment: thank you @egreg. I started to follow your logic and I think I have solved the problem. I edited the question to see if the logic is sound.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ and $y$ be in $Ha$. Then $x=ra$ and $y=sa$ for some $r$ and $s$ in $H$. Then $f(x)=rb$ and $f(y)=sb$. If $f(x)=f(y)$, then $rb=sb$, so $r=s$, so $x=y$. Thus, $f$ is injective.

Comment: but then your implications is also a=b is it not, which is not necessarily true since you have f(ra)=rb. maybe I am misunderstanding something @Gerry Myerson

Comment: I don't see where you get $a=b$. $f(ra)=rb$ isn't the same as $ra=rb$.

Comment: sorry. thank you though again for sending me on the right path. I started to follow your logic and some other suggestions and I think I have solved the problem. I edited the question to see if the logic is sound for my answer. @Gerry Myerson

Comment: Good, but in my opinion it would be better to post your work as an answer rather than as an edit to your question.